# EitherT with Reader generalizing over Reader input

Tags: scalaz

A standard construct in my code is a function that returns a Reader[X,\/[A,B]] and I would like to use the Either portion in a for comprehension, so I have been trying to write a function which will convert a function (X) => \/[A,B] into EitherT[Reader[X,\/[A,B]],A,B].

I can do this with a predetermined Type for X.  For instance:

```
  case class Config(host: String)

  type ReaderConfig[C] = Reader[Config, C]

  type EitherReaderConfig[A,B] = EitherT[ReaderConfig, A,B]

  def eitherReaderF[A,B](f: Config => \/[A,B]) : EitherReaderConfig[A,B] = EitherT[ReaderConfig, A,B](Reader[Config, \/[A,B]](f))

  eitherReaderF(c => \/-(c.host)).run(Config("hostname"))
```

However, I am having problems removing the Config type and generalizing over X.  This is because EitherT's first argument is expecting one argument in it's type construct: F[_], however Reader is defined as containing 2: Reader[A,B]

One of my attempts is to define a type in terms of an EitherT using type lambdas.

```
  type EitherReaderM[X,A,B] = EitherT[({type λ[α] = Reader[X, α]})#λ, A,B]

  def eitherReaderM[X,A,B](f: X => \/[A,B]): EitherReaderM[X,A,B] = EitherT[({type λ[α] = Reader[X, α]})#λ, A,B](Reader(f))

  val r: EitherReaderM[Config, Int, String] = eitherReaderM((c: Config) => \/-(c.host))

  val run = r.run /// type returns scalaz.Kleisli[[+X]X,Config,scalaz.\/[Int,String]]

  run.apply(Config("host")) // fails: value apply is not a member of scalaz.Kleisli[[+X]X,Config,scalaz.\/[Int,String]]
```

That last bit fails.  I feel like I'm close here.....

I'm not entirely sure what's going on yet, but I can run this with 2 calls to run.  One on the EitherT and then one on the Kleisli (which I'm not sure where it came in ).

```
  run.run(Config("host"))
```

However, even though this runs in the console, it doesn't actually compile.  I receive this error while compiling:

kinds of the type arguments ([α]scalaz.Kleisli[[+X]X,X,α],A,B) 
do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type F,type A,type B).
[α]scalaz.Kleisli[[+X]X,X,α]'s type parameters do not match type F's expected parameters:
type α is invariant, but type _ is declared covariant

[ERROR]   def eitherReaderM[X,A,B](f: X => /[A,B]): EitherReaderM[X,A,B] = EitherT({type λ[α] = Reader[X, α]})#λ, A,B

Answer (score 0):

And here we have it, the final, compiling version. I feel like it can be simplified a little more, but that is for a different day.

```
  type EitherReader[X,A,B] = EitherT[({type λ[+α] = Reader[X, α]})#λ, A,B]

  def eitherReader[X,A,B](f: X => \/[A,B]): EitherReader[X,A,B] = EitherT[({type λ[+α] = Reader[X, α]})#λ, A,B](Reader(f))
```

The allows me to replace Reader[X, A / B].apply with eitherReader[X,A,B].

Old:

```
  def getSub(id: Int) = Reader[Config, String \/ Sub](config => config.findSub(id).right)
```

New:

```
  def getSub(id: Int) = eitherReader[Config, String, Sub]](config => config.findSub(id).right)
```

Seems weird that I'm doing this simply for type conversion.  Probably means I'm overlooking something.